# How can I detect line wraps in XeLaTeX and change letter spacing accordingly?

Tags: xetex, wrap, line, letterspacing

I need to typeset a lot of short "phrases" (consisting of several words) strictly in one-line format (i.e., one "phrase" per line). I am also using fontspec under XeLaTeX to extend the letter spacing in my default typesetting style.
The problem arises when the "phrase" turns out to be a bit too long for the available text width (with the extended letter spacing).
Is there any way to detect line wrapping in XeLaTeX and automatically reduce letter spacing to make the "phrase" fit?

Example: the first parbox - the unwanted line wrapping; the second parbox - the desired result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}%
\parbox{4.5cm}{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=10.0}AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF}\\
\parbox{4.5cm}{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=0.0}AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF}
\end{document}
```

[image: XeLaTeX results]

==================

Edit/update: on the basis of egreg's code, I've tried to build something semi-working, and it 50% worked. In short, I tried to remove the "fitting cycle" (replacing it with just zero spacing) and converted "stretch" \makebox-es to "flush left":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\box_new:N \l__avilov_spaceout_try_box
\fp_new:N \l__avilov_spaceout_factor_fp

\NewDocumentCommand{\spaceouttowidth}{mm}
 {% #1 = width, #2 = text
  % initialize
  \fp_set:Nn \l__avilov_spaceout_factor_fp { 10 }
  \avilov_spaceout_main:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \avilov_spaceout_main:nn
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__avilov_spaceout_try_box
   {
    \addfontfeature{LetterSpace=\fp_use:N \l__avilov_spaceout_factor_fp}
    #2
   }
  \dim_compare:nTF { \box_wd:N \l__avilov_spaceout_try_box <= #1 }
   {% the box fits
    \makebox[#1][l]{\hbox_unpack_drop:N \l__avilov_spaceout_try_box}
   }
   {% reset the letter spacing to zero
    \fp_set:Nn \l__avilov_spaceout_factor_fp { 0 }
    \makebox[#1][l]{\hbox_unpack_drop:N \l__avilov_spaceout_try_box}
   }
   % uncomment the next line to print the factor (debugging tool)
   \makebox[0pt][l]{\tiny\fp_use:N \l__avilov_spaceout_factor_fp}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\rule{5cm}{0.4pt}

\spaceouttowidth{5cm}{AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF}

\spaceouttowidth{5cm}{AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FF}

\spaceouttowidth{5cm}{AAA BBB CC DD EE FF}

\spaceouttowidth{5cm}{AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF GGG}

\end{document}
```

[image: Update results]

As one can see, this (after changing [s] to [l] in the \makebox-es) ceased to react to LetterSpacing - and I don't understand why. Please help!

Also, I'd like to have a fail-safe behaviour that, if even the "shrunk" text does not fit, it wraps the line (i.e., has the parbox behaviour), not just protrudes to the right. I don't understand how to code it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do trial typesetting reducing the letter spacing factor as you go. Eventually, the text is typeset to the stated width by spreading a bit the interword spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\box_new:N \l__avilov_spaceout_try_box
\fp_new:N \l__avilov_spaceout_factor_fp

\NewDocumentCommand{\spaceouttowidth}{mm}
 {% #1 = width, #2 = text
  % initialize
  \fp_set:Nn \l__avilov_spaceout_factor_fp { 10 }
  \avilov_spaceout_main:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \avilov_spaceout_main:nn
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__avilov_spaceout_try_box
   {
    \addfontfeature{LetterSpace=\fp_use:N \l__avilov_spaceout_factor_fp}
    #2
   }
  \dim_compare:nTF { \box_wd:N \l__avilov_spaceout_try_box <= #1 }
   {% the box fits
    \makebox[#1][s]{\hbox_unpack_drop:N \l__avilov_spaceout_try_box}
    % uncomment the next line to print the factor (debugging tool)
    %\makebox[0pt][l]{\tiny\fp_use:N \l__avilov_spaceout_factor_fp}
   }
   {% reduce the letter spacing and retry
    \fp_add:Nn \l__avilov_spaceout_factor_fp { -0.1 }
    \fp_compare:nTF { \l__avilov_spaceout_factor_fp > 0 }
     {% still something to do
      \avilov_spaceout_main:nn { #1 } { #2 }
     }
     {% give up
      \mode_leave_vertical: \box_use:N \l__avilov_spaceout_try_box
      % uncomment the next line to print the message (debugging tool)
      %\makebox[0pt][l]{\tiny !!!!!~Doesn't~fit}
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\rule{5cm}{0.4pt}

\spaceouttowidth{5cm}{AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF}

\spaceouttowidth{5cm}{AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FF}

\spaceouttowidth{5cm}{AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF GGG}

\end{document}
```

For the picture I removed the `%` characters to get the debugging information.

Beware! This is slow.

[image]

Without filling the width and wrapping when the trials are unsuccessful:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\box_new:N \l__avilov_spaceout_try_box
\fp_new:N \l__avilov_spaceout_factor_fp

\NewDocumentCommand{\spaceouttowidth}{mm}
 {% #1 = width, #2 = text
  % initialize
  \fp_set:Nn \l__avilov_spaceout_factor_fp { 10 }
  \avilov_spaceout_main:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \avilov_spaceout_main:nn
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__avilov_spaceout_try_box
   {
    \addfontfeature{LetterSpace=\fp_use:N \l__avilov_spaceout_factor_fp}
    #2
   }
  \dim_compare:nTF { \box_wd:N \l__avilov_spaceout_try_box <= #1 }
   {% the box fits
    \mode_leave_vertical: \box_use:N \l__avilov_spaceout_try_box
    % uncomment the next line to print the factor (debugging tool)
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\tiny\fp_use:N \l__avilov_spaceout_factor_fp}
   }
   {% reduce the letter spacing and retry
    \fp_add:Nn \l__avilov_spaceout_factor_fp { -0.1 }
    \fp_compare:nTF { \l__avilov_spaceout_factor_fp > 0 }
     {% still something to do
      \avilov_spaceout_main:nn { #1 } { #2 }
     }
     {% give up
      \parbox[t]{#1}
       {
        \raggedright 
        \addfontfeature{LetterSpace=10}
        #2
        % uncomment the next line to print the factor (debugging tool)
        \makebox[0pt][l]{\tiny !!!!!~Doesn't~fit}
       }
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\rule{5cm}{0.4pt}

\spaceouttowidth{5cm}{AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF}

\spaceouttowidth{5cm}{AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FF}

\spaceouttowidth{5cm}{AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF GGG}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to set a minimum for letter spacing, say 5, with

```
\fp_compare:nTF { \l__avilov_spaceout_factor_fp > 4.9 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the "TeX magic" I am unable to cast... But this is not what I exactly want.I don't want to stretch the text to the given width, I'd like to go with my default letter spacing and "flushed-left" text as long as it does not overfill the line. And only if the line is overfilled/wrapped, then relax spacing (and, again, there is no need to fill the line exactly, just dropping the extra spacing to zero would be fine).

Comment: Please check the edit/update of my question: I've tried to convert your code to what I need, but failed. Please help! =)

Comment: @KonstantinAvilov I added a version that does what you asked for (I believe).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This version seems to work, and it actually does a bit more than required (it tries to fit the "phrase" with a lower, but non-zero LetterSpace). Although it is good for the overall looks, it may be detrimental for TeX's speed of compilation.